# is there a way of failing all the ansible roles if one of them failed?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a playbook with multiple roles and I want them fail if one of them fails.

here is my main playbook:

```
 ---
 - hosts: IOS
   connection: network_cli
   gather_facts: no
   roles:
     - wan_creating
     - infoblox_network_creation
     - infoblox_host_record
```

so everything runs fine but sometimes I might have duplicate host records in my ipam server in that case infolbox_host_record  role fails but the first two roles since they were successfully played they created the network which ends up lots of unnecessary networks in my ipam server. Is there a way of telling ansible if any of those roles failed I want to fail the whole playbook?

Comment: What do you mean with "fail the whole playbook"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. Once a role passed there is no way to change is's results.